# Postgresql fuzzy match extension giving out error

Tags: postgresql, fuzzy-logic

I am using PostgreSQL DB hosted on AWS. I am trying to use fuzzy logic, enabled its extension successfully.
But running the fussy match Query gives me an exception. Also verified, the extension is already enabled but still, Query failed.

```
**Query used to enable extension** - CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;
**DB version details** - PostgreSQL 9.6.6 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16), 64-bit
**Query for fuzzy match** - SELECT first_name FROM contact WHERE first_name % 'Eve' LIMIT 10;

**Error message -** SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying % unknown
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 49
  org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying % unknown
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 49
```

Comment: Does it help if you use `'Eve'::text`?

Comment: No i get the same issue.

Comment: Then there remain these explanations: a) you connect to a different database b) your `search_path` does not contain the `%` operator.